# When importing workspace, in my example it is in shared/components/Header.js, when typing at the end 'export default' it says 'type any' error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, yarn-workspaces

I an using yarn workspaces, and i have 3 packages: app, electron app using react, and shared for all the common stuff. When importing shared in the app or electron, it says that error in vscode:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6Wl0.png)

i dont know what to do :/ i tried everything. and the files arent ts, but js.

```
import { View, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';
import Header from 'shared/components/Header';

//const socket = new Socket("192.168.1.146", 8080, "http");

(async () => {
  //await socket.connect();
})();

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screenContainer: {
    flex: 1
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: 'cornflowerblue',
    marginTop: 50,
    alignSelf: 'center'
  }
});

const App = () => {
  /*useEffect(() => {
    if (socket.getSocket() != undefined && socket.getSocket().connected) {
      socket.getSocket().disconnect();
    }
  });*/
  return (
    <View styles={styles.screenContainer}>
      <Header />
      <Text style={styles.text}>I'm a React Native component</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  header: {
    paddingTop: 50,
    backgroundColor: 'red'
  },
  headerText: {
    fontSize: 22,
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    paddingHorizontal: 10
  }
});

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.header}>
      <Text style={styles.headerText}>I'm a shared component.</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Comment: Can you post the piece of code where you have this error?

Comment: @Giacomo edited the post to show the code

Answer (score 0):

create `fallback.d.ts` with content:

```
declare module '*';
```

And include it in your tsconfig.json https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#include (path to d.ts file relative to tsconfig.json path)

```
{
   "include": ["./fallback.d.ts", ...],
    ...
}
```

This will allow you to import from `js` files.

But imho better would be to convert `Header.js` file to `typescript`

Comment: how do i convert it and where to make the file?

Comment: By converting I mean changing file extension to .tsx

Comment: I have also updated my answer how to include d.ts file

Comment: somehow just by renaming the ending of the file to tsx and typing in the cmd inside the root folder of the project `yarn workspace shared add @types/react-native` the warning is now gone. why it was showing in the first place?